# Present or past tense

Tags: adverbs

Is the time adverb "this morning" used as present or past tense?  For example- 1) I come this morning and I came this morning. 2) I had come to your house this morning and I have come to house  this morning. Are these grammatically and syntactically correct? And is "this morning" correct to use in future tense?

Answer (score 1):

It is appropriate to use it for past, present, and future:

> I went to the office this morning.
>
> I am at the office this morning.
>
> I will be at the office this morning.

Comment: I am not able to understand this sentence in present tense "I am at the office this
morning."

Comment: here which morning we are referring?

Comment: "I am at the office this day" would be an awkward way of saying "I am at the office today" — does that help you understand "I am at the office this morning"? Or consider this example: "I am at the office this morning, but I will be at the warehouse this afternoon." It should be obvious that a present tense clause is set in the present time.

Comment: So, your supervisor, who works hundreds of miles away, calls your cell phone; he asks you what your schedule is. You, being a field service engineer, respond: I was at Customer A all day yesterday; I am at the office this morning and will be at Customer B this afternoon; and I will be at Customer C all day tomorrow.